# EHCache JMS Replication Node consistency tracking

Tags: jms, replication, ibm-mq, ehcache

I have a working proof of concept with EHCache using JMS Replication. I am using Websphere MQ as the message broker. I am able to successfully post messages to an MQ Topic which are then replicated accross all the cache nodes within my cluster but how can I validate that each Cache is in sync with its peers?

1. Is there a way I can utilize Websphere MQ to log each message received / sent from the topic?
2. Does anyone know if there's a way through EHCache to achieve something like this?

I know this is a high level question but I am not sure which direction to take with this. If I find help / solutions I will be sure to include source code on how to implement it in this post.

Answer (score 2):

To answer 1.

Since you are making use of publish/subscribe, you could simply attach a further subscription to the same topic and it will also be given a copy of each message sent and then that application can then save these off as log of all the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I don't need to track all the messages sent though, I need to be able to 1. Make sure the message is picked up by each node in my cluster and 2. that each node is in sync with the rest. Are you aware of a way to track through websphere mq all the subscriber / message confirmations?

Comment: Could you rewrite point 1. for what you actually want then please? Currently it says you want to log each message sent to the topic.

Comment: I think point 1 is explained clearly but let me rephrase to better suite your response. Is there a way I can configure MQ to log all the messages it receives from publishers as well as all the messages sent out to each subscriber? Im not that great with MQ so please correct me if my terminology is incorrect